# why some ios header are translated to pascal without cdecl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delphi

When i look how some ios header are translated to delphi, i can see for exemple

```
typedef void(^FIRMessagingConnectCompletion)(NSError * __nullable error);
```

that is translated :

```
FIRMessagingConnectCompletion = procedure(error: NSError) of object;
```

however i not understand why not with **cdecl**; ? because everything in ios must be with cdecl; Why it's not translated like :

```
FIRMessagingConnectCompletion = procedure(error: NSError) of object; cdecl;
```

---

**NOTE/EDIT**

To answer to Remy and Rudy and make everything clear i want to make a good example of one problem, taken from the original Delphi source

in delphi we have this interface declared :

```
  NSURLSessionTaskDelegate = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{C48E0AED-64F3-45A4-8D42-E3DB12F668E7}']

    procedure URLSessionTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionNewRequestCompletionHandler(session: NSURLSession;
      task: NSURLSessionTask; willPerformHTTPRedirection: NSHTTPURLResponse; newRequest: NSURLRequest;
      completionHandler: TFoundationCompletionHandler7); cdecl;

  end;
```

with

```
type
  TFoundationCompletionHandler7 = procedure(param1: NSURLRequest) of object;
```

so i decide to implement it like this :

```
  TMyNSURLSessionTaskDelegate = class(TOCLocal, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate)
  public

    procedure URLSessionTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionNewRequestCompletionHandler(session: NSURLSession;
      task: NSURLSessionTask; willPerformHTTPRedirection: NSHTTPURLResponse; newRequest: NSURLRequest;
      completionHandler: TFoundationCompletionHandler7); cdecl; 

  end;
```

but (you can try youself) as soon as you will do TMyNSURLSessionTaskDelegate.create you will receive an error `TFoundationCompletionHandler7 = procedure(param1: NSURLRequest) of object; is not a valid ObjectiveC type`

So where is the problem ? how to use NSURLSessionTaskDelegate ?

Comment: I can't check right now, but I *guess* that the Delphi `FIRMessagingConnectCompletion` is a callback for the Delphi wrapper (after all, it is a `procedure ... of object`, which is **a Delphi method**, not an Objective-C function), and then there is no need for `cdecl`. In other words: it is not a direct translation and it is not meant to be either. It is meant to be used the same way, that's all. The method is to be implemented and assigned on the Delphi side of the language barrier. Objective-C will never see this directly.

Comment: no typedef void(^FIRMessagingConnectCompletion)(NSError * __nullable error); is not taken from delphi, it's taken from the objective-c header, and it's translated in delphi as FIRMessagingConnectCompletion = procedure(error: NSError) of object; but it's the objective-c jar that will call this method

Comment: @Henry: you are missing the point.  `of object` is a Delphi-specific feature.  It defines a pointer to a non-static method of an object instance.  iOS **cannot** call that *directly*, because it can't setup the call stack that the method is expecting. So there is some Delphi magic in play here that translates the iOS header into a special wrapper that will intercept the actual iOS call and convert it into an appropriate Delphi call behind the scenes. That wrapper will use `cdecl` on the iOS side, but it does not need to use `cdecl` on the Delphi side.

Comment: @Henry: see what Remy said. This is a method pointer, and as such it is never pased to the Objective-C side. It is probably used **in the same way** a callback is used in iOS, **but it is not the same thing**. This is something that is called by the Delphi wrapper for an iOS object. The iOS object itself will never see this. That is why it is not necessary to be a direct translation with `cdecl`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you comment deserve to be an answer :) so as i understand it's delphi in the background that translate the of object to something that the ios can use. I have no idea how he can do this because it's ios that call from where he want the procedure and will not take care to pass also the ref to the owner object that if i not make mistake is necessary to call an object member

Comment: @Henry: `of object` can only be used with Delphi objects, not iOS objects. So, there has to be an intermediate wrapper implemented by Delphi that contains the actual `cdecl` callback that is given to iOS directly, and an associated `of object` variable. When iOS calls that callback, the wrapper then calls whatever Delphi object method has been assigned to the variable, if any.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: thanks Remy, however can you look the question, i just edit it to add a note for you regarding your explanation

Answer (score 1):

The declaration you have shown for Delphi's `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` interface does not match [Apple's declaration of `URLSessionTaskDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate), and as such cannot be used as-is in Objective-C.  And that is what the compiler is complaining about.

The types for the completion handlers used by `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` parameters *should* look more like this instead:

```
TFoundationCompletionHandler6 = procedure(param1: NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition; param2: NSURLCredential); cdecl;
TFoundationCompletionHandler7 = procedure(request: NSURLRequest); cdecl;
TFoundationNeedNewBodyStream = procedure(param1: NSInputStream); cdecl;
```

(`of object` replaced with `cdecl`)

That is clearly a bug on Embarcadero's part when translating iOS headers (and frankly, I'm surprised that ever made it through testing without being spotted).

Then, you would implement your delegate class like this:

```
type
  TMyUrlSessionHTTPRedirection = procedure(
    session: NSURLSession; task: NSURLSessionTask;
    willPerformHTTPRedirection: NSHTTPURLResponse;
    var newRequest: NSURLRequest) of object;

  TMyNSURLSessionTaskDelegate = class(TOCLocal, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate)
  public
    OnHttpRedirection: TMyUrlSessionHTTPRedirection;
    ...
    procedure URLSessionTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionNewRequestCompletionHandler(
      session: NSURLSession; task: NSURLSessionTask;
      willPerformHTTPRedirection: NSHTTPURLResponse; newRequest: NSURLRequest;
      completionHandler: TFoundationCompletionHandler7); cdecl;
    ...
  end;

procedure TMyNSURLSessionTaskDelegate.URLSessionTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionNewRequestCompletionHandler(
  session: NSURLSession; task: NSURLSessionTask;
  willPerformHTTPRedirection: NSHTTPURLResponse; newRequest: NSURLRequest;
  completionHandler: TFoundationCompletionHandler7); cdecl;
var
  finalRequest: NSURLRequest;
begin
  finalRequest := newRequest;

  if Assigned(OnHttpRedirection) then
    OnHttpRedirection(session, task, willPerformHTTPRedirection, finalRequest);

  completionHandler(finalRequest);
end;
```

You would then create an instance of `TMyNSURLSessionTaskDelegate` and assign a Delphi object method to the `OnHttpRedirection` member, and then pass the delegate instance to iOS.  When appropriate, it will call the delegate's `urlSession()` method, which will call the `OnHttpRedirection` handler.

Until Embarcadero fixes their bug, you will have to redeclare the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` interface in your own code with the correct type declarations.

Comment: thanks remy! however even with `TFoundationCompletionHandler7 = procedure(request: NSURLRequest); cdecl;` you will still have the error is not a valid ObjectiveC type :( I think it's also another bug of Delphi (yea Delphi look like bug on top of other bug), because the procedure MangleType (in Macapi.ObjectiveC) don't care about tkMethod ...

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

- The Delphi wrapper exposes the methods of the iOS object
- These are not called directly. Each call to a method of the wrapper makes the wrapper call the corresponding method of the iOS object, with the proper parameters.
- The iOS object calls the callback, which is intercepted by the wrapper. This makes the wrapper call **the Delphi version** of the `FIRMessagingConnectCompletion` method (the one without `cdecl`). The code in that Delphi method is completely in Delphi and runs in the Delphi context. The original iOS object never sees this, nor does it need to.
- The method can be implemented completely in Delphi, and is called by a Delphi object. It is most likely a method of a Form. That is why it is declared as `of object`, like an event, and is not declared as `cdecl`, as this completely runs in the Delphi context.

*The declaration is quite similar to the original, to make it look **as if** you are implementing the callback, but in fact you are implementing a Delphi event. This makes it easier to translate iOS examples and other iOS code, although the underlying types/code and infrastructure are quite different.*

Comment: thanks Rudy, however can you look the question, i just edit it to add a note for you regarding your answer