# How to execute a procedure when we know only it's address?

Tags: delphi

i have this procedure declaration:

```
procedure (options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions); cdecl;
```

One function (in ios) return me an address/pointer to one procedure to execute. The procedure have the declaration i wrote above. how to call this procedure knowing only it's address from delphi ?

Comment: What exactly is giving you an **untyped** pointer to a procedure?  Can you provide more context?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks again, because of the error you explain here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651633/why-some-ios-header-are-translated-to-pascal-without-cdecl/43690370#43690370) i must replace `completionHandler: TFoundationCompletionHandler7` by `completionHandler: pointer` :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the address to a pointer variable and type-cast it, eg:

```
type
  TProcType = procedure(options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions); cdecl;

var
  Ptr: Pointer;
  options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions;
begin
  Ptr := ...; // the address here
  TProcType(Ptr)(options);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  TProcType = procedure(options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions); cdecl;

var
  Proc: TProcType;
  options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions;
begin
  @Proc := ...; // the address here
  Proc(options);
end;
```

Comment: It's just ironic that your sample type starts with a `T`, otherwise it's always good practice to prefix all such types with a `T`. Of course you know this, just might want to edit your answer as to not throw off future developers reading this :-)

Comment: why not start with `T` here ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau : i m unlucky it's not work for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651633/why-some-ios-header-are-translated-to-pascal-without-cdecl/43690370#43690370 :( maybe the procedure must be declared as procedure (options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions); **of object;** cdecl; ?